# Can I use this site offline?

Tags: support, export

My question is really simple, Is it possible to have the contents of this site offline? Sometimes I have to travel to really small towns in my country which doesn't have internet connection.

Thanks

Comment: You can use [Stackprinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) and save pdf copies.

Comment: [There's a StackApp for that.](http://stackapps.com/q/3610)  (Disclaimer: I have never used this.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer I tried on Windows 8 and Linux (ubuntu), but I found very hard to make it work, maybe is there another tutorial online?

Comment: @user85493: As I mentioned above, I've never used this before. I really have no idea about any additional support you can find online. Perhaps you could ask in a comment on the StackApps page, or if there is a particular difficulty you are having, ask on [su].

Comment: @ArthurFischer thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

[Stackdump](https://stackapps.com/q/3610), linked to in a comment by Arthur Fischer, is probably the way to go if you want to have a copy of the entire site with you. (Disclaimer: I never used Stackdump either.)

But this being summer time for most of planet's population, I see another offline use case: take your favorite questions with you [on a beach](http://tetrahedral.blogspot.com/2011/03/6-months-in-rio-smale-solution-to.html) in printed form. There is, of course, [StackPrinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/) which can grab the list of your favorites; however you'll still have to print them one by one.

So, in case anyone wants to print all their favorite questions at once (no answers included), I added this function to **[Save as LaTeX](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29863189/mse/savetex.html)**. Sample output: [Rahul's favorite questions](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29863189/mse/rahuls-favorite-questions.pdf). (This script is still under development, and the fact that so much valid MathJax is invalid LaTeX does not help at all. E.g., for this sample I had to fix a few LaTeX errors manually.)

Comment: I tried on Windows 8 and Linux (ubuntu), but I found very hard to make it work, maybe is there another tutorial online?

Comment: @user85493 It does look resource-hungry, may be this is the reason. The better pave to ask questions about Stackdump is on its page on StackApps. Maybe the author will be able to answer, or an experienced user. Also, if you can specify what parts of the site you really need on your trip, there may be a better way. For example, one can easily download posts from Data Explorer, 50000 posts at a time.

Comment: @user85493 If you can specify which tag(s) are of interest to you, I'll look into making something self-contained that can be downloaded as a zip file.  (Also, "pave" was meant to be "place"; that was autocorrect...)

Comment: If you could download the abstract algebra tag it would be nice, thank you very much!

Comment: @user85493 I'm looking into it now. Downloading information is the easy part: the queries [all questions with given tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/210230/all-questions-with-a-given-tag) and [all answers with given tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/210231/all-answers-with-a-given-tag) do this. The challenge is in how to present this 33MB of information in usable form...